# In Python, how to avoid calling __init__ twice in a class derived from a class with super() in its __new__:

Tags: python, super, derived-class

I am new to python. Somehow

```
__init__
```

is called twice for a class that is derived from another class using

```
super()
```

My question is how to avoid this because I have a very expensive computation there.

```
class A(object):
  def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    print("Class A: __new__")
    obj = super(A, cls).__new__(cls) # super is used here
    obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    return obj
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.attrib = x+1

class B(A):
  def __init__(self, x):
    print("Class B: __init__")
    self.prop = 2*x # some expensive computation

a = A(10) # a test call

b = B(20) # Q: here, how to avoid calling __init__ twice in class B?
```

Edit:
Thank you both for answers. My real code is diagonalising a large sparse matrix using arpack built in scipy library. I am calling a class SpLuInv(LinearOperator) defined in arpack.py where class LinearOperator is defined in interface.py, both files are attached: [arpack.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/arpack.py) and [interface.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/linalg/interface.py). When I call SpLuInv(), its **init** is called twice. From you answers, I think i need to remove obj.**init** that's in **new** of LinearOperator().

Thank you Brendan Abel for your answer and Akshat Mahajan and Mike Graham for your comments. Removing

```
obj.__init__
```

from the

```
__new__
```

of

```
LinearOperator()
```

solved the problem. :)

Comment: Do you really need to inherit from `A`? Why not just define the specific methods you want from it in `B`?

Comment: Defining `__new__` is virtually always a suboptimal approach. Consider sharing your real, real code.

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't manually call `__init__` in `__new__`.  The object returned from `__new__` will automatically have `__init__` called.

You *should* be calling the superclass `__init__` in *all* your classes, even if they only inherit from `object`.

The only time this is a problem are for things like *singleton* objects, which often return an already `__init__`'d object from `__new__`.  In that case, you just store the instance of the class as a class attribute and return directly from the `__init__` if the attribute is set.

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Class A: __new__")
        obj = super(A, cls).__new__(cls) # super is used here
        return obj

    def __init__(self, x):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        self.attrib = x+1

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x):
        print("Class B: __init__")
        super(B, self).__init__(x)
        self.prop = 2*x # some expensive computation
```

Comment: Nit: `metaclass.__call__` will only call `__init__` if `__new__` returned an instance of the type (including subclasses). This matters if you override `__new__` to return a cached object (then `__init__` will be called multiple times necessarily) or an object of a different class (then `__init__` will not be called for you at all).

Comment: Why is it a good practice to call super().__init__() in all classes?